# Thunar file manager disrupts background on xfce4?

Tags: xfce, desktop-background, thunar

I've found on a few different installations of Ubuntu that when I'm running xfce4, and I open up Thunar for any reason, it causes the background to blank out. The problem isn't resolved until a restart. Anybody know a way to prevent this?

Also, how can I restart the background daemon without restarting the computer?

Comment: Do you have 'xfdesktop' installed and working as a process in Autostart? Also, the problem is a clash between Thunar and Ubuntu's Nautilus as default file manager.  Does it work with 'xfdesktop --reload' ?

Comment: I do have xfdesktop installed and working as a process.

xfdesktop --reload didn't work, but xfdesktop -W did. I've uninstalled Nautilus. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, happy your issue is solved